# Limpíar el storage de Laravel con artisan o cmd

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, storage, artisan

Estoy usando Laravel 8, el detalle es que tengo una libreria que me genera imagenes que se guardan en el storage, por lo que cada vez que hago un

**php artisan migrate:refresh --seed**

Se borran mis registros de la base de datos, pero aun se mantienen las imagenes.
¿Existe algun comando para limpiar todo lo que contenga Storage? Ya saben algo como el comando para limpiar cache...

**php artisan cache:clear** nose, talvez un **php artisan storage:clear** o algo asi... es tedioso tener que ir a la carpeta y eliminar todas las imagenes manualmente.

Comment: Con `php artisan list` podes ver los comandos artisan disponibles. No hay uno que alivie tu tedio pero es muy simple de hacerlo tu mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto no lo trae pero tienes la opcion de crear tu comando personalizado

```
php artisan make:command StorageClear
```

Te invito a leer la documentacion oficial donde indica como crear y registrar tu comando personalizado
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#generating-commands

Editas el comando generado para crear tu script de eliminado de carpeta:

```
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

$file = new Filesystem;
$file->cleanDirectory('storage/app/imagenes');
```